# Перевести строку в дату php

Tags: php

Есть строка:

```
Tue, 08 Aug 2017 13:32:56 +0300
```

Как ее перевести в дату правильно? На выходе желательно получить дату:
DD.MM.YYYY H:M

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$date = new DateTime('Tue, 08 Aug 2017 13:32:56 +0300');
echo $date->format('d.m.Y H:i') . PHP_EOL;
```

Про форматы: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.date.php

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = "Tue, 08 Aug 2017 13:32:56 +0300";
$str_to_date = date("d-m-Y H:i", strtotime($str)); // в формате, который просили
echo "$str<br>$str_to_date";
```